# How to make this div go over embedded video

Tags: css, flash, z-index

I have a video on a page and I cannot get the play list control to appear above it. I have set the z-index of the play list to 99999 but the video is still being rendered on top of it.

Here is an image that shows the problem and the CSS. I have tried setting the z-index of the video to -1, 1 etc.

[image]

So my question is, how do I force the flash video to appear below the play list?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

add:

```
<param NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">
```

as param in the the flash movie's Object tag, and DIVs and other layers will be able to jump on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

What Enrico and thisMayhem said.. however, instead of using "transparent", try "opaque" first. "Transparent" forces a different composition mode that makes Flash execution slower and has issues of its own (specially in Firefox). For normal div composition on top of the movie, 'opaque' is normally enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "wmode" as "opaque" (not transparent) in both embed and object tags.

See more info here: http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html

But be sure what to use it for and that you really need it. Check out this Tinic Uro post:
http://www.kaourantin.net/2010/02/core-animation.html