# Is there any plugin or a way in which i am able to create overlays over html5 videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm using [videojs](http://www.videojs.com) to embed videos into my html file.

I'm able to listen to certain events like play,pause,duration etc.,

Using these events i want to create an overlay over the video where the user can read some text or click a button or whatever. Basically,a sort of Interactive media.

This transparent layer has to be in the video.

I have looked at [popcornjs](http://www.popcornjs.org) and it does look awesome . But it doesn't solve the purpose.

How can go about doing this?

Any help or tips is much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: What are you looking for that Popcorn doesn't do?

Comment: @brianchirls I want to interact with the user inside the video frame , if possible .

Comment: You can definitely do that with Popcorn. It's just a question of finding (or writing) the right plugins.

Comment: @brianchirls Yes. But the only problem with popcorn is, when the video is played full screen , the other interactive frame gets hidden . I don't want that to happen.

Comment: You can do that too. Just make the element containing the video and Popcorn's overlay elements fullscreen. It's a little tricky to get scaling right, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the CSS Z-Index property? 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

It may just do the trick. Once you place a div on top of the video you can do all kinds of things, place canvas on there, draw things even.

Good luck.

PS: You may also run into this...
[How to make this div go over embedded video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238560/how-to-make-this-div-go-over-embedded-video)